# Need to remove duplicate rows for one item type but not the others

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a basic select statement like this:

```
SELECT  
        ID, ProcedureCode, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), StartTime, 112) AS 'DateOfService',
        SessionID'

 FROM dbo.TASK
```

The results are like this:

```
 ID     ProcedureCode   DateOfService   SessionID
A164686     0034        20131014        9708
A164686     0034        20131021        9832
A164686     0002        20131007        9578
B463333     0002        20131003        9523
B463333     0002        20131009        9665
B463333     0002        20131016        9763
```

Note for ID B463333 there are three 0002 procedures for the month of October.  I want to eliminate the extra two leaving just the most recent (based on DateOfService).

I know I could accomplish this by using a row_number() partition but I don't want that logic to apply to the other procedure codes, like 0034, I only want to remove the extra 0002 procedure codes if they exist.  Having duplicate 0034 is fine but not 0002.

Any thought about how to accomplish this?  The only way I thought of being able to do it is make a temp table with the 0002 procedure codes and doing a UNION to the select above but that seems messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a ranking function like `ROW_NUMBER` with a common-table-function:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
     SELECT  ID, 
             ProcedureCode, 
             CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), StartTime, 112) AS 'DateOfService', 
             SessionID,
             RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, ProcedureCode 
                                     ORDER BY StartTime DESC)
     FROM dbo.TASK
     WHERE  ProcedureCode = '0002'
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

One advantage is that you can change it to do a select easily to see what youn are going to delete.

**Edit**: If you actually don't want to "eliminate" (delete) records but omit unwanted rows from the resultset  you can use this query:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
     SELECT  ID, 
             ProcedureCode, 
             CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), StartTime, 112) AS 'DateOfService', 
             SessionID,
             RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, ProcedureCode 
                                     ORDER BY StartTime DESC)
     FROM dbo.TASK
)
SELECT ID, ProcedureCode, DateOfService, SessionID
FROM CTE
WHERE ProcedureCode <> '0002'
OR    RN = 1
```

Comment: wouldn't this apply to non 0002 ProcedureCodes as well?

Comment: @user2932397: It will delete only duplicates according to ID, ProcedureCode. However, i must admit that i've read only the first paragraph not the part that starts with _"I know I could accomplish this by using a row_number()"_. **Edit**: I have edited my answer. You can simply add a `Where` to the `CTE` or to the `DELETE` statement.

Comment: I don't see how this solution will work since there is a WHERE clause for ProcedureCode = '0002' which means I would be excluding 0034 and the several other procedure codes.

Comment: @Baub: These are your words: _"but I don't want that logic to apply to the other procedure codes, like 0034, I only want to remove the extra 0002 procedure codes if they exist. Having duplicate 0034 is fine but not 0002."_ That means you only want to delete duplicate `0002` rows(as @user2932397 has also mentioned). Have i misunderstood it?

Comment: Yes, I only want to delete the duplicate rows for 0002 but duplicates for 0034 (and others) are acceptable.

If I run your select statement I will never have procedure codes of 0034, but I need to include those.